# RegEx Google Apps Script with replaceAllText

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I've tried to replace some text in Google Slides with `replaceAllText`, it works fine if I provide the string, however I can't find the solution for regex.

What I want to change is:

`N = 500`

Regex variations I tried with `replaceAllText`:

```
/N [=, 0-9]*/
"N [=, 0-9]*"
"N = [0-9]*"
"N = \d*"
/N = \d*/
```

but nothing worked.

How can I use `replaceAllText` with regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

[replaceAllText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#replaceAllText(String,String)) doesn't support regular expressions, but exact substring matches.

#### Solution:

You should be using [find(pattern)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#findpattern) instead:

> **find(pattern)**: Returns all the ranges matching the search pattern in the current text range. The search is case sensitive.

#### Code sample:

For example, if you wanted to find and replace all regex matches in the presentation, you could do the following:

```
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

function findAndReplace() {
  var pres = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slides = pres.getSlides();
  const pattern = "N = \\d*";
  slides.forEach(slide => { // Iterate through every slide in the presentation
    slide.getShapes().forEach(shape => { // Iterate through every shape in the slide
      const textRange = shape.getText(); // Get shape text
      const matches = textRange.find(pattern); // Find matches
      matches.forEach(match => match.setText("REPLACED TEXT")); // Replace text
    });               
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- The expression in the code sample above (`N = \\d*`) has two backslashes, because, as the docs say, `any backslashes in the pattern should be escaped`. A possible alternative could be `N = [0-9]*`.